# PowerShell: Expanding Exception object properties in language file

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script that has a lot of strings that need to be output either to a log or to the screen. To help simplify maintenance, I created a very simple lang.xml file where I store the strings. A lot of the strings display information that's held in variables in the script, so I wrote a little cmdlet that will expand the strings in returned xml #text nodes.

This works pretty great up until I use this in catch block to format error messages. When I attempt to expand the Exception message, for example, an empty string is returned. Even when I pass the Exception object to the cmdlet it expands to an empty string. Below is a snippet of XML and the cmdlet, with example output.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <lang>
    <keyword name="ERRMessage">
      <string>"Error message: $($Exception.Exception.Message)"</string>
    </keyword>
  </lang>
</xml>
```

Cmdlet:

```
function Read-Lang
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [Parameter( Mandatory=$true,
                ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
                HelpMessage="The name atttribute of a keyword in lang.xml")]
    [string[]] $Keyword,
    $Exception
  )

  begin
  {
    if ( $global:LangXML -eq $null )
    {
      Write-Debug "Language XML has not been loaded, loading now."
      $global:LangXML = [xml] (Get-Content '.\lang.xml')
    }
  }

  process
  {
    foreach ( $name in $Keyword)
    {
      $Query = "/lang/keyword[@name=`"$name`"]/string"
      $global:LangXML.SelectNodes($Query) | 
        ForEach-Object { $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_."#text") }       
    }
  }
}
```

Example:

```
try { get-content goo -ErrorAction Stop} catch { Read-Lang -KeyWord 'ERRMessage'  -Exception $_ }
```

Expected output:

```
Error Message: Cannot find path 'path\to\goo' because it does not exist.
```

Actual output:

```
Error Message:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested you code with xml example.

It works for me, after I removed the `</xml>` closing tag  in `lang.xml` file, that gives me error here

`$global:LangXML = [xml] (Get-Content '.\lang.xml')`

this what I got:

```
PS C:\ps> try { get-content goo -ErrorAction Stop} catch { Read-Lang -KeyWord 'ERRMessage'  -Exception $_ }
Error message: Impossibile trovare il percorso 'C:\ps\goo' perché non esiste.
PS C:\ps>
```

p.s.: error is in italian, I'm on it-it culture system but is the right error.

Comment: That's really strange - the whole '</xml>' was just a typo, always get in the habit of closing tags. It's working for me now, though I'll mark yours as an answer because your good luck was what I need.

Comment: Glad to share luck! :) Thanks!